# How to make the rewrite work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got this URL: `host.com/john?result=success`

I need it internally rewritten to: `host.com/?name=john&result=success`

Tried this: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA]`

And it only rewrites it into: `host.com/?name=john`  - `&result=success` is lost in this case.

As far as I know `[QSA]` should be keeping original query string too, but it gets lost.

All help is much appreciated in this matter.

**[EDIT]:**

This is my full htaccess, i'm just bypassing one folder before this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(admin) - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: I just tested `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA]` in my environment and it works as expected. The `QUERY_STRING` results in `name=john&result=success`. There must be some other problem with either your environment or PHP script.

Comment: You were right, I had additional php processing which was stripping `result=success` from the query string. The issue is now resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Don't know how to mark comment as a correct answer.

Comment: Good to know it worked but `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|)/?$` is still not correct regex since it will also match empty string hence it will rewrite `http://example.com/` to `http://example.com/?name=` giving you an empty `GET` variable.

Comment: An empty variable is fine, I can validate it later on with PHP.

Comment: Sure you can validate that in PHP. You can skip `mod_rewrite` and handle this super simple rule in PHP also but that is not the point. If you're relying on `mod_rewrite` then better to use it to the fullest.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems to be faulty here.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Same result here `result=success` is lost

Comment: Do you have other rules too in this .htaccess?

Comment: do you think making sure the requested is not file or folder would make the rewrite code work? Removing of the `|` after `0-9]+` doesn't change much neither.

Comment: Hmm your code looks different from mine. I have used `[L,QSA]` flags also

Comment: `QSA` was stated in the original question, didn't help, and `L` only makes it stop on the match, not much of a difference.

Comment: This rule worked fine in my testing. Are you sure your are dumping `$_GET` first thing in your `index.php`?